# Referencing a specific figure in Microsoft Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word, photos, label

Referring to the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to be able to reference the figure in the body of the text properly without having to change them manually every time I add a figure label before that body of text. However, I don't know how to do it aside from adding caption labels, which won't work for cases where I have more than one reference to the figure (at least I don't know how to do that properly anyway). How would you recommend accomplishing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done by Insert -> Reference -> Cross Reference.

Answer (score 1):

Insert --> Reference --> Caption will automatically number and label the figure for you.

Under caption you go to "Label" and tell it the object is a figure and it will renumber your figures automatically and also insert them into the Table of Contents if you create one.

Then "cross reference" as the other answer states to have your text reference the caption.