# How to refer to a figure in Microsoft word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Suppose I have two figure in my document, figure 1 and 2. I refer to the figure 2 in the test like: "...,see figure 2." Now if I put another figure before figure 2, its number should become figure 3, and "...,see figure 2." should automatically become "...,see figure 3.".

How can I do that? I could not understand the answer in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/127211/referencing-a-specific-figure-in-microsoft-word-2003).

Comment: What don't you understand?  You simply insert a cross-reference as the answer suggests.  Word Help on F1 will explain it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be able to reference your figures, you have to do the following steps

1. Create a caption for each of your figures (References → Insert Caption or right-click on your image → Insert Caption). This creates the references that could be referenced with the next step

[image]

2. Reference your figures with Insert → Cross Reference and select Figure.

[image]

[image]

Refresh your cross references with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>F9</kbd>. F9 refreshes.

However, you don't have to do this often. This refreshes the displayed text. The actual references are always up-to-date. You only have to refresh before printing or PDF-ing.

**Reference Link:**
[Here's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-cross-reference-300b208c-e45a-487a-880b-a02767d9774b) the documentation from the official website.

**Reference Images:**

Comment: When I add a third photo between figures 1 and 2, the captions change automatically but the reference should be updated manually by "update field". Is it possible to update the cross reference automatically too?

Comment: @yashar: updated answer

Answer (score 0):

For the captions, the safest way to do it (Word can get very confused) is by creating a new numbered paragraph style ("Figure Numbered" would be a reasonably intuitive name for it).

Then all you have to do is select the style for the line that you want to use for the caption, and the numbering will take care of itself automatically.

You can create cross references to the style.

If you save the style to your normal template, it will be available in all new documents.

Comment: How do you cross-refrence this style?

Answer (score 0):

You can't cross-refer to styles; only to bookmarks.

Word generates a bookmark for every line that has a numbered style.

Click the Cross-reference button, and select "Numbered item" in the pop-up window.

You can then select any line that has a numbered style, and create a cross reference to it.

[image]